# ios & s3: download image from s3 using url

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

Is it possible to download image from s3 using url in iOS so I don't have to use the s3 sdk?

It's more convenience to download the image using url and NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest, since I get the url directly.

I tried to do so, but always get timeout error.

If I switch the url to some other image from the web that's not in s3, I could download the image successfully.

The s3 image could be view on the web using url directly.

Code:

```
var urlString = self.thumbnailImageURL
var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 90)
var urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler:
             {(response: NSURLResponse!, data:NSData!,error:NSError!)-> Void in
                  if let e: AnyObject = error {
                     println("Image Download Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
               }else{
...
```

I got "Image Download Error: The request timed out."

Answer (score 1):

Hi it is nice question.

And yes it is possible to save image without using of the s3 libraries.

I can provide my solution using `ASIHTTPRequest`.

```
- (ASIHTTPRequest *)newHttpRequest
{
    NSString *path = [MEDispatcher sharedInstance].profileData.picture;
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];

    ASIHTTPRequest *result = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [result setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];

    [url release];
    result.timeOutSeconds = MERequestTimeoutInterval;

    return result;
}
```

It is smile request that take data about the image from url. And in response i pars all info about image.

Comment: Hi Oleg, could you take a look to my code? I don't know why it does not work for s3, yet it could download image from other url. And how long does it take to download an image from s3?  Thank you!

Comment: My friend probably you need to set timeoutInterval for the NSURLRequest that is more than 90 sec.Also check permission of you're bucket in amazon s3.

Comment: I could view the image through url in my browser. Does it mean the image could be downloaded in ios apps?

Comment: Seams to me it is enough to download image.Could you provide Url that you use.

Comment: NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; try this one to set url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59302/discussion-between-fuiiii-and-oleg-gordiichuk).

Comment: if i help you please rate me =)

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I change "https" to "http" in url, it will work.
So I simply do this:

```
var urlString = self.thumbnailImageURL
urlString = urlString.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(
                Range<String.Index>(start: urlString.startIndex,end:advance(urlString.startIndex, 5)), withString: "http")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                               if ( !error )
                               {
                                    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                                    completionBlock(YES,image);
                                } else{
                                    completionBlock(NO,nil);
                                }
                           }];
}
```

Make sure the image on S3 is set to public.

Comment: Perfect... You don't need to install S3 SDK. The above answer will do the trick. Thanks a lot.. it saved a lot of time...